# Chrome Extensions content calls callback to background but parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to set up a background script fetching data from content periodically and write it to a file (kind of webpage scraping)

Unfortunately I got stuck at the very beginning:

Background sends a message to content and the callback is called but the parameter is not passed correctly, it's "undefined" whatever I try...

## Manifest:

```
    {
 "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

        "background": {
            "persistent": false,
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "content_scripts": [{
            "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }],
        "browser_action": {
            "default_title": "Test Extension"
        },

        "permissions": ["activeTab"]
    }
```

## content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        sendResponse({data: "goodbye"});
    }
});
```

## background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: 'report_back'}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at ...

I'm guessing you are clicking on the extension icon when you are in a tab like `chrome://extensions`

Try clicking on it from any other website and it should work.

Comment: You're right! But interestingly if the failure is thrown once I get it everytime independent which tab I'm selecting. I have to restart (or at least reload the extension)
But this is just the first step: What I really need is a periodical loading (every 1-5 seconds) of a dynamically changed field on a website. So instead of "onClick" I'd like to use the setInterval method but how do I get the tabID?

Comment: @WolfgangHaring First, no you don't have to reload the extension, only the current page you're on. Second, you need the same function happening when you click the extension icon but you want it to happen always on every page every 1-5 seconds? I think I answered your current question but if you need anything more on chrome extensions I'll help.

Comment: I appreciate! I'll try with reloading the page. I need just the interval thing. The click on the extension button was my starting point.